# Replacing Ext.reg() (xtype) in ExtJS4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, multi-select

I want to use the MultiSelect from 3.3 in Ext JS 4, as described in this previous question:

[Why are the Ext JS multiselect item selector files not included in the Ext JS 3.3 download and where are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243944/why-are-the-ext-js-multiselect-item-selector-files-not-included-in-the-ext-js-3-3)

It seems like the way to register **xtypes** has changed in Ext JS 4.  When I try to import this widget,along with ItemSelector.js, I get an error on Ext.reg().

```
Ext.reg('multiselect', Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect);

//backwards compat
Ext.ux.Multiselect = Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect;
```

How do I change wdigets to get them to work in Ext JS 4?

Comment: Looks to me like you can use `Ext.ComponentMgr.registerType` which is where `Ext.reg` used to point. I'd post an answer, but I haven't actually got a working Ext4 application yet...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Ext JS 4 way is to use the new class system to create your widget:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system/

Make sure you assign your widget an alias using the "widget" namespace.  For example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect', {
    extend: 'ClassNameYouAreExtending',
    alias: 'widget.multiselect'
});
```

Then you can refer to the widget by the xtype 'multiselect'.  When you use an xtype in Ext JS 4 it looks for a class with an alias of 'widget.[xtype]'.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify the code to get the MultiSelect component running on ExtJS 4. Here are few changes that you will have to do:

1. Class definition. ExtJS 3.x used Ext.extend to extend. With the new version, you will have to use Ext.define
2. In the new version, you can represent a class name as string. Due to this, I think you will not require the Ext.reg method anymore. The Component Manager class to not have register function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're diving into pre-beta territory, so to some extent you're going to have to look at code and figure it out.  There is some explanation of the new class system in the [blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system/) introducing it, and there will be a comprehensive migration guide before 4.0 final comes out.  I would definitely pursue this in the Sencha 4.0 forums though since that's where all the Ext 4 experts will be hanging out.

Comment: We're out of beta and 4.0 has been released.