# Extjs: problem in Ext.reg()

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I got the following error with Extjs 4:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reg'**

I add the .js file which contains following code.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id:'ms',
    totalProperty:'totalCount',
    root:'rows',
    url:'http://localhost:8080/ezDI/myservlet',
    fields:[
            {name:'un'},
            {name:'pwd'}]
});

Ext.ns('Example');
 // example grid
Example.Grid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            store:myStore,
            columns:[{
                //id:'ms',
                header:"UserName",
                width:40, sortable:true,
                dataIndex:'un'
            },{
                header:"PassWord",
                width:20,
                sortable:true,
                dataIndex:'pwd'
            }],
            viewConfig:{forceFit:true},
            loadMask:true
        }; // eo config object

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

        // call parent
        Example.Grid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

        // load the store at the latest possible moment
        this.on({
            afterlayout:{scope:this, single:true, fn:function() {
                this.store.load({params:{start:0, limit:30}});
            }}
        });

    } // eo function initComponent

});

Ext.reg('examplegrid', Example.Grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Replacing Ext.reg() (xtype) in ExtJS4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380770/replacing-ext-reg-xtype-in-extjs4)

You create an alias when you extend the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing ExtJS 3 instead of ExtJS 4

You should read the [upgrade guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/upgrade)

Here is a small code comparison to illustrate the differences.

```
// Ext 3:
Ext.ns('MyApp'); // required in Ext 3
MyApp.CustomerPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    // etc.
});
Ext.reg('examplegrid', Example.Grid);

var panel = new MyApp.CustomerPanel(cfg);


// Ext 4
Ext.define('MyApp.CustomerPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.examplegrid'
    // etc.
});
var panel = Ext.create('MyApp.CustomerPanel', cfg);
//or: var panel = Ext.widget('examplegrid', cfg);
```